Make cannonjs group from sub groups cubes (from .obj format)
This is JS object , it comes from blender added obj groups and it is a cube geometry.
I dont need other geometry just simple cube.
Cube vertices with some scale and translation in form of [ [1,1,1] , [1,1,1] ... ]
I use CANNONJS to make static wall for example and only working for me is Box/Cube collider. Also not important is visual for colliders (visuals comes from imported obj file)
Other cube is positive look screenshot  (4 2 by X).
Standard for cube i take from -1 to 1
it means world position.x of this cube is  -3
0: (3) ['-4.000000', '-1.000000', '1.000000']
1: (3)['-4.000000', '1.000000', '1.000000']
2: (3)['-4.000000', '-1.000000', '-1.000000']
3: (3)['-4.000000', '1.000000', '-1.000000']
4: (3) ['-2.000000', '-1.000000', '1.000000']
5: (3) ['-2.000000', '1.000000', '1.000000']
6: (3) ['-2.000000', '-1.000000', '-1.000000']
7: (3) ['-2.000000', '1.000000', '-1.000000']

My code :
                var body = new CANNON.Body({
                mass: 0,
                position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 0, 0)
            });
                        App.scene[n.name].mesh.groups.forEach((group, indexGroup) => {
                // We can add the same shape several times to position child shapes within the Compound.
                console.log( '>>>>>GROUP>SUB VERTS>>>>>>>', group)
                var collectX0, collectX4, collectY0, collectY1, collectZ0, collectZ2;
                group.groupVert.forEach((vert, index) => {
                    // console.log(index , '>>>>>GROUP>SUB VERTS>>>>>>>', vert)
                    if(index == 0) {
                        collectX0 = parseFloat(vert[0])
                        collectY0 = parseFloat(vert[1])
                        collectZ0 = parseFloat(vert[2])
                    }else if (index == 1) {
                        collectY1 = parseFloat(vert[1])
                    }else if (index == 2) {
                        collectZ2 = parseFloat(vert[2])
                    }   else if(index == 4){
                         collectX4 = parseFloat(vert[0])
                    }
                    // index 0 vs 4 MAKE X SCALE NARUTE VERT VALUES
                })

                // X
                // Probable cube one be always - other + 90%
                // -.55 0.55 ~ 1.1
                var calcX = collectX4 - collectX0;
                var calcXWorldPos = (collectX4 + collectX0) / 2;
                calcX = calcX / 2;
                var calcY = collectY1 - collectY0;
                var calcYWorldPox = (collectY1 + collectY0) / 2;
                calcY = calcY /2;
                var calcZ = collectZ2 - collectZ0;
                var calcZWorldPos = (collectZ2 + collectZ0) / 2;
                calcZ = calcZ / 2;
                console.log("calcYWorldPox is calc x ", calcXWorldPos, " y " , calcYWorldPox , " z " , calcZWorldPos)
                var shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(Math.abs(calcX),Math.abs(calcY),Math.abs(calcZ)));
                // OFFSET 
                // calc from center 0,0,0 probably
                // calcX / 2 HALF to find center of cube then distance from 0,0,0 relative OBJ center...
                //  -4 -2 
              var offsetX =  calcX/2
                body.addShape(shape,  new CANNON.Vec3(calcXWorldPos, calcYWorldPox, calcZWorldPos))
            })

This looks nice
But i wanna use multiply cubes (for big map) who is not in center pivot (0,0,0) of relative position of object.
My idea is to make a very small cube collider in center (no affect on player moving)
and he will be my normal connection woth  general rotation in scene.
Other collider type cubes need to follow center cube in domain of rotation.
I will update Q for more information and progress.
Any suggestion ?

I found cannon.js/demos/compound.html

I tested objs no need to be side by one works with exstra translation.
Also works with multiply call of body.addShape
body.addShape () 
body.addShape ()

Still i need to find bounds of cube and then make Cannon.Box with correct scale params...
in this picture for example i wanna collider for left and right but not for center cube. I alredy  know by tag name "COLLIDER" that come from blender editor.

